# Possibility to intercept OSGi service resolving

Tags: java, osgi

I have rather big set of services registered with `registerService`. For simplicity let's assume they are lookup by some property `name`. So pair of invocation is straightforward (I use pseudocode for property spec):

```
context.registerService(
    IMyService.getClass().getName(), myServiceInst, {"name"="a"})
```

After that on client side:

```
context.getServiceReferences(IMyService.getClass().getName(), {"name"="a"})
```

For some reason I cannot register all possible combinations of `name`. Is it possible to intercept all OSGi queries so I could create services on the fly when they are queried?

I would like have basic solution that works on all layers of OSGi - it mean that code above and code with (for example) Declarative Service will work the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Service Hooks in the core specification. They allow you to find out who is waiting for what services. Notice that this might imply parsing the filter if you're interested in what properties they're waiting for.

Comment: just bad news. I've dive into this topic and it is appeared in core-spec: *The Event Listener Hook and Find Hook both allow the interceptor to remove elements from a collec-
tion and not add elements. The reason is that adding almost inevitably violates framework invariants 
that can trip the receivers.*

Comment: So? It also explains that you add new services through the normal means ... The hooks only allow you find out what people are waiting for, registering is normal plain old OSGi ... as it obviously should be.

Comment: But I need exactly add semantic - to create service on the fly when user provides corresponding filter expression. So hooks could work well if add service allowed.

Comment: What are you missing when you have context.registerService() to add a new service?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a couple of options:

**Option 1:**

If you need only one Service object by client bundle (where the client bundle identifies the key-value pairs) consider using http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/ServiceFactory.html. I think the javadoc is pretty self explaining and you can find easily usage samples in google. In this case you have to implement ServiceFactory and you have to use that one in Declarative Services (please correct me if I have not used declarative services only blueprint)

**Option 2:**

Create your services with the help of ConfigAdmin. You create a configuration with your client bundle and your service provider bundle will catch that and export the necessary service. After the service is provided you can catch the new service registration with the client. You can find nice doc at http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-config-admin.html. Well in case of this option you will be able to get more services by client bundles but I do not think you can use this with Declarative Services (You must catch the configuration changes programmatically).

**Option 3:**

Instead of registering IMyService register IMyServiceFactory as an OSGi service. that has a createService(name) function. In this case in the client bundles you have to take care of the lifecycles of your IMyService objects (if no more IMyService is used you can "unget" IMyServiceFactory).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Let me start from end - **Option 3**  is not a case because IMyServiceFactory will not be found against `{name=unknown}` - and you propose me to invent my own query engine on this factory. **Option 2** near the same - I cannot foreseen all possible names to lookup hence the cannot be statically put to config file. I promise you evaluate **Option 1** as soon as possible - thanks on it.

Comment: Option 2 is not about a static config file but it is about the Configuration Admin chapter of OSGi Enterprise specification. You can query out the ConfigurationAdmin OSGi service and register new configurations via it programmatically (basically key-value pairs). On the other hand you can register listeners and catch the configuration change events.

Comment: about option 2 - you don't get a point (btw, I use Config Admin on my project and know it well) - you already describe the behavior: *You create a configuration with your client bundle...* - but I don't know what configuration should be created